# run code when a table is ready after $(selector).load(URL)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I load a table into the document and want to bind a function of footbale to it. But whatever I try (ready,load), I cannot get an onload event to do the job. My workaround is a timeout. That is not pretty. But it proofs that the code has no errors.

```
<body>
  <div id="table_wrapper"></div>
</body>
<script>
  $("#stable_wrapper").load("rss2table.php"); // <table id="termine">

  setTimeout(() => {           
      $('#termine').footable({
      components: {
                filtering: FooTable.MyFiltering
      }
   });
 }, 1000); // min. timeout to run propper
</script>
```

When I try this

```
$('#termine tbody').ready(function() {
    // Run code
    console.log("ready");

    $('#termine').footable({
        components: {
            filtering: FooTable.MyFiltering
        }
    });
});
```

I get "ready" in the console, but the rest won't work.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Where did you define `footable()`? Is it a custom event?

Comment: The load method has a callback, put your code in that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `footable()` is a valid library that you're using, then to fix the problem you should use the callback of `load()` to execute your logic after the AJAX call completes.

In theory the `setTimeout()` could do this too, but is not considered the best method as you either make the user wait too long, if the request completes before 1s, or it runs before the request completes and nothing happens. The latter of these seems to be the case here, given the behaviour you describe.

To define the callback, place your logic in a function which you provide as the second argument of `load()`:

```
$("#stable_wrapper").load("rss2table.php", function() {
  $('#termine').footable({
    components: {
      filtering: FooTable.MyFiltering
    }
  });
});
```